# Error when installing on other device Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-manifest

Please help me fix this on my project,

Project minimum sdk when i create is 4.4 kitkat
Upon running on my device which is OREO OS.

And when i run on my other device which is in Lollipop OS
the error message will appear
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6ul0.png)

Error Message in my console

pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.teamcipher.mrfinman.mrfinmanfinal
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]

$ adb shell pm uninstall com.teamcipher.mrfinman.mrfinmanfinal
Unknown failure (Failure - not installed for 0)
Error while Installing APK

**My Manifest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM" />




<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <receiver android:name="Receiver.Notification_receiver" />
    <receiver android:name="Receiver.Notification_receiver_debt" />
    <receiver android:name="Receiver.Notification_receiver_goal" />
    <receiver android:name="Receiver.Notification_receiver_bills" />

    <service android:name="Services.RealtimeBudgetRemCheck"/>
    <service android:name="Services.BillCheck"/>
    <service android:name="Services.GoalCheck"/>
    <service android:name="Background.background"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyOwn">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity_dashboard"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyOwn" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity_expense"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyOwn" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity_login"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyCustomTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity_income"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyOwn" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity_editbudgetplan"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyOwn"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity_add_category"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyOwn" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityRegistration"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyCustomTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityRegistration2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyCustomTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity_myincome"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyOwn" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity_transactions"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyOwn" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity_my_budget_plan"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyOwn" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity_my_goals_add"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyOwn" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity_my_debt_add"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyOwn" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity_my_bills"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyOwn" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity_my_bills_add"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyOwn" />
    <activity
        android:name=".DialogTransactionDetails"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Testing"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity_set_budget"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyOwn" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Template"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyOwn" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Biller.Activity_dashboard_biller"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Biller" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Admin.Activity_dashboard_admin"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Admin" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity_forgot_password"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyCustomTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity_Confirmation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyCustomTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity_Registration_biller"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyCustomTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity_reset_pword"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyCustomTheme" />
    <activity android:name=".PopUp.BillPopUp"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert"/>

  <!--  <service android:name="Services.FirebaseMessagingServices">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name="Services.FirebaseInstanceIDServices">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>-->

</application>
```

Comment: Delete build folder inside app directory.

Comment: Wow!  Thank you so much! It saves my time :)